# Office de/du tourisme

Tags: grammaire, usage

J'ai rencontré ces deux variantes, « de » à Èze et « du » à Cannes.

Laquelle est correcte et pourquoi ?

[image] [image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Si l'on analyse la construction grammaticale :

- « office du tourisme » = « office » + « de » + « le tourisme », avec l'[article défini](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_d%C3%A9fini) *le*, qui ici désigne un concept dans son ensemble. Il s'agit de l'office qui s'occupe du tourisme en général.
- « office de tourisme » = « office » + « de » + « du tourisme », avec l'[article partitif](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_partitif) *du*, qui signifie que l'office s'occupe d'une partie du tourisme.

Les deux constructions sont donc possibles grammaticalement. La construction habituelle avec d'autres mots similaires, et celle qui me paraît la plus logique, est avec l'article défini ; par exemple, on parle toujours de « ministère du tourisme », jamais de « *<s>ministère de tourisme</s> ».
Le mot *office* dans ce sens est rare en français moderne, il ne s'emploie guère pour autre chose que le tourisme (on parle plutôt d'*agence*, de *bureau*, de *centre*, etc.).

Dans l'expression « office de/du tourisme », je ne perçois pas de nuance de sens — pour moi, les deux sont rigoureusement synonymes, quelle que soit leur décomposition grammaticale ou étymologique. En regardant un peu sur le web, j'ai l'impression que les deux sont utilisés indifféremment, y compris au sein d'un même texte. J'ai l'impression toutefois que cette indifférence est principalement française, et que la Belgique et le Québec tendent à favoriser *du* (sans l'utiliser exclusivement).

L'usage, en ce qui concerne spécifiquement l'office de/du tourisme, a toujours été partagé, avec une légère majorité pour *du* :

[image: office de tourisme,office du tourisme]

Comment: Merci pour si profonde réponse!

Comment: @jFrenetic : L'usage parlé courant est "Office du tourisme". Je n'ai jamais entendu un Français parler de "l'office de tourisme"...(et je suis français habitant en France...)

Comment: @Trimok, Merci! Néanmoins, comme vous avez vu sur l'image au-dessus, c'est possible :)

Comment: @jFrenetic : Je parle de la langue parlée, la recherche Google se fait sur l'écrit. Même s'il y a des panneaux "Office de tourisme", par exemple, si quelqu'un pose une question, il demandera : "Où est l'office du tourisme ?"

Comment: @Trimok Je suis Français (et Belge) habitant en France (mais passant régulièrement en Belgique) et je dis « office de tourisme ». En fait, « office du tourisme » me semble bizarre »

Comment: @Édouard : OK, donc nous avons des habitudes personnelles linguistiques différentes. Moi, c'est juste le contraire, "Office de tourisme" me semble étrange...

Answer (score 5):

On peut aussi aborder la question en se demandant pourquoi parfois office de — est suivi de **article défini + nom** et parfois du **nom sans article**.

Quelques recherches rapides de dénominations officielles (corpus français de France google) avec le mot office :

1. Office de la Culture
2. Office de protection contre les rayonnements ionisants...
3. Office de Génie Écologique
4. Office Français de Protection des Réfugiés (OFPRA)
5. Office français de l'immigration et de l'intégration
6. Office de Justification de la diffusion (OJD)
7. Office de Préservation du Bâtiment

Si dans le cas d'office de la Culture on ne peut pas hésiter sur la présence de l'article défini, pour les autres exemples ci-dessus il me semble que l'hésitation est possible.

Je n'ai pas de réponse mais je ne pense pas qu'on puisse dire que l'Office de la culture s'occupe de toute la culture du lieu où il est implanté (ce serait quand même un peu présomptueux), pourquoi Office de culture me choque-t-il ? Serait-ce  à cause de la polyvalence du mot culture et donc pour éviter la confusion entre la culture de l'esprit et celles des céréales ? Pas sûr car la présence de la majuscule ne suffirait-elle pas à lever l’ambiguïté ?

L'organisme qui fédère les offices de/du Tourisme en France s'appelle [Offices de Tourisme de France](http://www.offices-de-tourisme-de-france.org). Peut-être pourraient-ils dire si eux voient une différence entre *de tourisme* et *du tourisme* ?

Comment: +1. SVP, prière d'éclairer ces 2 questions SVP au sein de votre réponse (et non pas en tant que commentaire) ? **1.** Pourriez-vous détailler `la polyvalence du mot culture et donc pour éviter la confusion entre la culture de l'esprit et celles des céréales` ? Y a-t-il cette polyvalence ? **2.** Je ne comprends pas l'usage de `eux` dans votre dernière phrase ? Pourquoi pas `si + ILS + voient ...` ?

Comment: @LePressentiment: Je ne veux pas ajouter à cette réponse de réponses à d'autres questions. J'ai répondu à tes questions sur le chat : http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/12538216#12538216 :

Answer (score 3):

Aucune des deux ne me choque et la terminologie officielle semble hésiter entre "[Office de Tourisme](http://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichCodeArticle.do;?idArticle=LEGIARTI000020899067&cidTexte=LEGITEXT000006074073)" et "[Office du tourisme](http://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichCode.do?idSectionTA=LEGISCTA000006163394&cidTexte=LEGITEXT000006070162&dateTexte=19820302)"

Comment: Mais, j'ai toujours pensé que "de + article" sert à exprimer posession. Voir [ici](http://french.about.com/od/grammar/a/de-vs-du-de-la-des_4.htm) par exemple. Est-ce que la phrase "office du tourisme" correcte?

Comment: That would be a descriptive "de", like "livre d'étudiant" in the link you posted.

Comment: But descriptive goes *without* article, and du = de + le, which is how possessive form is constructed.

Comment: "tourisme" might "own" the "office", like "Hôtel des impots". In any case, "de" + article is not always possessive but might just mean "about" like in "Palais de la découverte" or "Hotel du Nord".