# Quand « du » et quand « de » ?

Tags: grammaire, articles, contractions, de, articles-definis

Quelle est la différence entre l'article partitif *du* et l'article *de* ? Quand est-ce que je dois utiliser *du* plutôt que *de* ?

En plus, pourquoi doit-on dire « je mange du poisson » mais « je bois de l'alcool » ? Le poisson et l'alcool sont tous les deux masculins.

Comment: Deux excellentes réponses déjà ici: http://french.stackexchange.com/a/1788/358 et  http://french.stackexchange.com/a/1787/358  mais je ne demande pas la fermeture parce que la question qui a amené la réponse n'apparaît pas facilement (mal posée je pense) et c'est en anglais... donc à voir avec les mods comment on peut régler ce problème.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Office de/du tourisme](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/8102/office-de-du-tourisme)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

« Du » est la contraction de « de le ». Quand on devrait dire ou écrire « de le » et que « le » est un article, on utilise en fait « du ». Ce n’est pas un choix, cette contraction est obligatoire, qu'il s'agisse d'un article partitif ou d'une préposition *de* suivie par l'article *le*.

> La voiture de Jacques
>   La voiture de la juge
>   *<strike>La voiture de le procureur</strike>
>   La voiture **du** procureur

L’avant-dernier extrait est fautif : il faut utiliser « du », comme dans le dernier exemple.

Lorsque l’article « le » doit s’élider en « l’ », c’est cette contraction qui a priorité : on écrit donc « de l’ » et pas « du ».

> La voiture de l’huissier

Lorsque « le » est un pronom, la contraction ne se fait pas.

> Je lui ai demandé de le faire.

Answer (score 2):

Je ne suis pas tout à fait certain dans quelles circonstances le mot *de* se considère « article » et non pas « préposition », mais je peux dire que *de* ou *d'* s'utilise :

- au lieu de *un*, *une*, *du*, *de la*, *de l'*, ou *des* pour introduire un complément d'objet direct dans un contexte négatif (par exemple, après un adverbe négatif tel que *pas* ou *jamais*, ou un sujet négatif tel que *rien* ou *personne*).

  - « Il n'y pas d'arbres là-bas. »
  - « Personne n'a de vie parfaite. »
- dans le langage soutenu, au lieu de *des* quand le substantif est précédé par un adjectif.

  - « De telles choses m'intéressent. »
- même dans le langage courant, au lieu de *des* quand le substantif est précédé par *autres*.

  - « D'autres choses m'intéressent. »
- dans des expressions de quantité telles que *beaucoup de*, *plusieurs de*, *trop de*, et *une dizaine de*.