# When to use “de” or “des” after nouns and after “beaucoup”?

Tags: prépositions, articles, accord

I am trying to grasp the difference between *de* and *des* after nouns and “beaucoup”.

1. I am aware of the construction *beaucoup de* (always singular) + nouns.

   > J'ai beaucoup de livres.
   >
   > J'ai peu de défauts.

   What is the rule behind the use of just "de" ? Any other cases like this? Can we say that this applies for adjective/adverb?
2. After nouns, I saw

   > Justificatif de domicile
   >
   > Nombre d'écrans

   Why are we using “de” here ? Why not “justificatif du domicile” or “nombre des écrans”? What is the rule here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Several constructions exist that link two nouns with the preposition *de*.

1. The preposition *de* can be used to characterize the kind of object we are talking about. It is in this case used without an article, and the following characterization can either be singular or plural.

   > le sac de sable
   >    le sac de fraises

   This is what happens with “justificatif”.

   > le justificatif de domicile

   You can think of it as a single word, like “brosse à dents”.
2. Other usages of *de* exist, for example, to express possession (but [not only](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/de#Pr.C3.A9position_1)). In this case:

   - to form an indefinite reference use *d'un/d'une* (preposition *de* + article) + noun

     > le sac d'un ami
   - to form a partitive (or indefinite plural) reference use *de* (preposition *de*, **alone**) + noun

     > plusieurs sacs d'amis
   - to form a singular definite reference to an object use *du*/*de la*/*de l'* (preposition *de* + article) + noun.

     > le sac du facteur
   - to form a plural definite reference to particular objects  use *des* (preposition *de* + *les*) + noun (plural form).

     > le sac des élèves

---

The funny thing is that many of your examples (“beaucoup”, “peu”, “nombre”) are very particular examples, because each corresponds to two different fixed locutions. The first ones are very similar to first type of constructions:

- *beaucoup de bateaux*: a lot of boats
- *peu d'élèves*: few students
- *nombre d'instituteurs*: numerous teachers

The second ones act as a particular kinds of pronouns and are quite similar to the second type of constructions as they refer to a definite set:

- *beaucoup des bateaux (que …)*: many of/among the boats (which …)
- *peu des élèves (que …)*: few of/among the students (whom …)
- *nombre des candidats (que …)*: a large number of/among candidates (whom …)

It is also possible to use *un/le nombre* as a usual noun. In this case it has to be preceded by an article and it means “number”. It is followed by a bare *de*:

- *le nombre de participants*: the number of participants

It's similar for *un/le peu* which means “a/the little” (and can also be used for some uncountable plurals):

- *un peu de sable*
- *un peu de fraises*

Comment: I don't understand the second part where you write "beaucoup des bateaux". It seems not right, so if you can give example, it would be nice.

Comment: @Yohann: *Beaucoup des bateaux que j'ai vus avaient une coque bleue.*

Comment: It is crystal clear like this, thank you

Comment: Thanks Stéphane. It seems that _beaucoup de, peu de, nombre de_ are more of the total number in general, where with _des_ , it means more of certain individuals in the collection ? What would mean _number of students_ , as in _the number of students in the class is 10_ ? Can we safely say that _noun1 + de + noun2_ always hold true if _noun2_ characterizes/complement _noun1_ and not _noun1 of noun2_ ?

Comment: @Kenny: precisions added.

Comment: Maybe a detail worth noting: _des_ is actually a contracted form of _de les_ (same as _du_ is the contraction of _de le_). This can help understand the difference between _beaucoup de bateaux_ ("Many boats have a sail.") and _beaucoup des bateaux_ ("Many of the boats I've seen had a blue hull.") for instance.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez: Thanks. Nevertheless, I saw _Préfecture, Bureau des étrangers_ instead of _Bureau d'étrangers_. To me _étrangers_ is more of a characterization for _bureau_. It does not really mean _étrangers_ who _owns_ the bureau (in term of posession _des (de les)_) as in _le bureau du chef_, _le bureau du collègue_

Comment: Hehe, “bureau d'étrangers” could mean “office full of strangers”. It's always difficult to tell which construction should be used. Sometimes the choice is [arbitrary](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/8102).

Comment: Lol I suppose I am digging deep enough I starts to encounter demons now. And it's just something quotidien like this.. Then _bureau d'étrangers_ **always** means _office full of foreigners_. It never means _foreigners office_ as a characterization?

Comment: Indeed *bureau* is usually followed by a *de* that attaches a topic to it. “Bureau de la pêche”, “Bureau de l'administration”, “Bureau des étudiants”. Adding a complement does not change the meaning. It remains a normal “bureau”. In the one exception I can think of, “Bureau de change”, the article drops.

Comment: Yet _le sac de sable_ et _le sac de fraises_ still remains a normal _sac_ , non?

Comment: Not really as it means the contents more than the container in this case. And by the way, the container would be *un sac à sable* or *un sac à fraises* (if such a thing existed).

Comment: Isn't it the same with _bureau_ ? _bureau_ is not _made of étrangers_. The container is unchanged, only the content. _bureau des étrangers, bureau des étudiants_ and _sac de sable/sac de frites_ both talk about the content, with the container unchanged. The following is not a very good example because it refers to another meaning of _bureau_, but what I am trying to say is in the sense of _made of_ similar to _un sac à sable_ : _un bureau à bois_

Comment: Also, _bureau de tabac_ :). Which category does this falls into?

Comment: In “sac à sable” the meaning is “made for”; “en” would be used for “made of” like in “sac en papier”. Though sometimes “de” can also be used for that, like in “pont de pierre”. “Bureau de tabac” is clearly not a usual “bureau”; this is another good example.

Comment: Those have been great explanations. Thanks Stéphane.