# Is it ever okay to use "beaucoup des" ?

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, articles, de

For example in the sentence:

> J'aime beaucoup _____ danses indiennes

Would the blank be filled by 'de' or 'des'?

Comment: Use **de** if you like many indian dances. *Des* is not used in this case and sound weird. For this case *les* is better in normal speaking if you generally like indian dances .

Comment: This was already answered here: http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/13872/when-to-use-de-or-des-after-nouns-and-after-beaucoup

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to use “de” or “des” after nouns and after “beaucoup”?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/13872/when-to-use-de-or-des-after-nouns-and-after-beaucoup)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Short answer : "***de***" is correct.

---

Now "*beaucoup des*" is not wrong *per se*, but it means something different. In this context, ***des*** means **"of the"**.

> *J'aime beaucoup **de** danses indiennes* = I like many indian dances.
>
> *J'aime beaucoup **des** danses indiennes* = I like many **of the** indian dances.

In most cases you can only use "*de*", because you're saying you like a lot of something in general. Using "*des*" means you like a lot of items in that subcategory, which is a less common thing to say.

<sub>In French, "*des*" is "*de*" + "*les*", which directly translates to "of" + "the".</sub>

Comment: *J'aime beaucoup* des *danses indiennes*" sonne mal aux oreilles francophones et jugé 'wrong' (mais pas toujours) par  http://french.about.com/od/mistakes/a/beaucoupdes.htm

Comment: @cl-r: Je suis bien d'accord. Et pourtant, la réponse à "is it ever okay ?" est **oui**. Pour un étudiant que juge un professeur, c'est *wrong*, mais du point de vue de la langue française, c'est grammatical et veut dire quelque chose. Si ma réponse n'exprime pas ça clairement, les suggestions d'amélioration sont très bienvenues.

Comment: Et pour ne citer que l'Académie française : "[Il avait conservé beaucoup des habitudes du XVIIe et du XVIIIe siècle.](http://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Acad%C3%A9mie_fran%C3%A7aise_%E2%80%93_r%C3%A9ception_de_M._Nisard)"

Comment: C'était un usage plus courant du temps de M. de Feletz que de nos jours, et c'est pourquoi l'académicien utilise cette tournure datant du XVIIe siècle, pour être dans le ton. Un étudiant annonçant "J'aime beaucoup des fraises" se fera reprendre immédiatement (en tout cas en France), c'est aussi un parlé de très jeunes enfants (qui découvrent les pièges du français). Ce n'est pas parce que *beaucoup des* est possible qu'il faut l'utiliser dans ce cas précis.

Comment: @cl-r "J'aime beaucoup des fraises" est très improbable mais "J'aime beaucoup des danses indiennes" est possible, par exemple à un festival où des danses de tous les pays sont présentées, un observateur qui a apprécié certaines des danses indiennes peut très bien dire "J'aime beaucoup des danses indiennes", c'est à dire, "J'aime beaucoup certaines des danses indiennes que j'ai vues ici" alors qu'avec "j'aime beaucoup de danses indiennes", le lien avec les danses présentées est moins net.

Comment: @jlliagre "J'aime beaucoup *les* danses indiennes de ce festival" est une tournure plus usuelle pour dire en général ; "J'aime *beaucoup* certaines *des* danses indiennes de ce festival" (beaucoup n'est pas suivi par un nom) en cerne quelques unes ; mais devant un nom, seul l'usage *beaucoup de* est correct... si j'en crois Le Robert.

Comment: @cl-r "Et j’admire beaucoup des écrivains du passé." Jean d'Ormesson. http://www.letemps.ch/Page/Uuid/6e095cfc-de28-11e0-9486-62f0f64eb087/anti-Le%C3%A7on_d%C3%A9l%C3%A9gance

Comment: @jlliagre suivi de :  Je suis d’une certaine façon une sorte de «dernier des Mohicans», c'est une tournure vieillie, comme l'Académie... à la question *"Is it **ever okay** to use “beaucoup des” ?* je n'encourage pas *des*. Le choix de *de* comme première réponse de Nikana va dans ce sens.

Comment: Pour enrichir la discussion, il existe des tournures alternatives à « beaucoup des » (« la plupart des », ...). @cl-r « J'aime beaucoup les » n'est pas la même chose que « J'aime beaucoup des » : on ne se rend pas compte que certains éléments ne sont pas aimés. Bien entendu, il y a une graduation au sein de l'ensemble, mais une tournure semble tout inclure alors que l'autre exclut explicitement.

Comment: In my opinion, your answer is misleading, "Beaucoup des" is always wrong when you use it to say "I like reading a great amount of  books" for instance. J'aime lire beaucoup de livres. "J'aime lire beaucoup des livres" is always incorrect (see my answer)

Answer (score 1):

Pour compléter l'exemple :

> J'aime *beaucoup* ***de*** danses indiennes

Devant un nom qui représente une entité, ou qui ne présente pas de particularité, mettre *de*.

Si l'on reste dans les généralités, on dira plutôt :

> J'aime beaucoup ***les*** danses indiennes.

S'il s'agit de dénombrer :

> J'aime *beaucoup **des*** danses indiennes du Kérala [, mais pas toutes].

Ce sont des danses définies et identifiables une à une.

"On aime [beaucoup] les films d'un réalisateur",  "On aime des films [et pas d'autres (films)]", on ne dit pas "On aime beaucoup des films", mais "On aime beaucoup des films de ce réalisateur".

Answer (score 0):

"I like reading a great amount of books" (a lot of books)
"J'aime lire beaucoup *de* livre."

You have to use ALWAYS "de" after "beaucoup" and never "des".
It's the rule.

But, when you say "J'aime lire *beaucoup des* auteurs du Moyen-âge", here the role of "beaucoup" is completely different.
It means a great amount among...  I like reading a lot among the Middle age author.

So, in the first case, you use "beaucoup de", when it means a great amount. A lot...

In the second case, "beaucoup de" meaning a great amount among another category (like then you use "Most of the authors), and you can use "des".

If it's simply "a lot", it's always "beaucoup de".
You have 2 different expressions, with 2 different meanings, "beaucoup de" and "beaucoup des".