# Emploi de "de" et "des"

Tags: usage, articles

J'ai rencontré le panneau

> Office de tourisme et des congrès.

Pourquoi cette différence ? à savoir **de** et **des**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parce qu'il n'y a qu'un tourisme (concept) mais qu'il y a plusieurs congrès (événements spécifiques).

On peut noter qu'*office de tourisme* est en concurrence avec *office du tourisme*. Voir [Office de/du tourisme](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/8102/office-de-du-tourisme?rq=1)

Comment: Merci. Mais pourquoi pas office du tourisme et des congrès ? Il me semble plus logique. De+le->du et de+les->des, non ? Sinon, plus simplement office de tourisme et congrès ?

Comment: *Office du tourisme et des congrès* est aussi possible et utilisé. Regarde la réponse de Gilles dans le lien fourni. *Office de tourisme et congrès* semble plus rare, mais c'est aussi une combinaison possible.

Comment: Merci encore. C'est noté.☺